# adding image in database using javaGUI in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to add image attribute to my existing table, with attributes customerid, name, email and address. How can I put image of the different customers in the column(image) also how to resize the image?  I am using java gui for displaying output in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer save the image url in database, but if you want, look this

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/InsertpicturetoMySQL.htm

Comment: How to save image url in database? Can you give me an example.

Comment: When you save a new image, copy to some folder and save the path of file in database, when you need to load the image, get the image from folder with path name.